# How to convert a double to hex?

Tags: ruby, double, hex, byte

How do I convert a ruby float/double to high endian order hex with high bytes and low bytes.

EXAMPLE:

```
start with 99.0
```

end up with

```
40 58 C0 00   00 00 00 00
high bytes    low bytes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, [like Patrick said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728121/how-to-convert-a-double-to-hex/728202#728167), it doesn't take a lot to convert past using `Array\#pack`.

```
irb> [99.0].pack('G').split('').map { |ds| ds[0] }
#=> [64, 88, 192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
irb> _.map { |d| "%02x" % d }
#=> ["40", "58", "c0", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00"]
irb> [99.0].pack('E').split('').map { |ds| ds[0] }
#=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 192, 88, 64]
irb> _.map { |d| "%02x" % d }    
#=> ["00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "c0", "58", "40"]
```

So it depends whether you want to unpack it with the high-order byte in the zero index or the low order byte in the zero index:

```
      E     |  Double-precision float, little-endian byte order
      G     |  Double-precision float, network (big-endian) byte order
```

Answer (score 0):

The array class has a pack method:

```
a = [99.0]
s = a.pack("d")
s
=> "\000\000\000\000\000\300X@"
```

This gives you a byte string, but converting from that to hex for printing should be trivial.

If you want to go the other way, the string class has an unpack method:

```
s.unpack("d")
=>[99.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby 2.x:

```
pry(main)> [99.0].pack('E').split('')
=> ["\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\x00", "\xC0", "X", "@"]
pry(main)> _.map { |ds| ds.unpack("H*").first }
=> ["00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "c0", "58", "40"]
```